# Merge [highlight] into [highlighting] or vice versa

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently on SO there are 2 almost identical tags:

- [highlight](/questions/tagged/highlight) (697)

and

- [highlighting](/questions/tagged/highlighting) (518)

Please merge  and synonymize one into another.

Comment: Don't we have some sort of rule that tags should be able to stand on their own? Does [tag:highlight] really do that? Hmm.

Comment: And yes, the above comment is a proper question, not rhetorical. It didn't warrant its own question though, in my opinion.

Comment: how is **highlight** or **highlighting** programming related anyway?